# Using ant script within maven ant plugin

Tags: maven, ant

I am using the ant maven plugin to call a legacy target inside a maven build. When I run the pom file, it throws an error on a missing ant file:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (clear-generated-javascripts) on project documentation: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERROR] C:\Development\documentation\build.xml:308: Problem: failed to create task or type propertyfile
[ERROR] Cause: the class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.PropertyFile was not found.
[ERROR] This looks like one of Ant's optional components.
[ERROR] Action: Check that the appropriate optional JAR exists in
[ERROR] -ANT_HOME\lib
[ERROR] -the IDE Ant configuration dialogs
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Do not panic, this is a common problem.
[ERROR] The commonest cause is a missing JAR.
[ERROR]
```

I have tried to add the necessary dependency as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ant</groupId>
    <artifactId>ant-optional</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I looked into the ant-optional jar file and the class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.PropertyFile is indeed there. I tried to add the jar into the lib directory inside $ANT_HOME with no luck. Any light would be apreciated.

Comment: I do not want to include the targets explicitly inside my pom file because the ant file will continue to be modified elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is **plugin related**, thus adding the correct jar as a normal `<dependency>` won't solve the problem.

You need to add the JAR containing `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.PropertyFile` to %ANT_HOME%\lib

Dependencies are meant to be part of your project, they won't be deployed inside your ANT folder without special configuration.

Comment: I suspected that the maven classpath space was not the same as the one ant was using, anyhow I also tried to add the jar to the lib folder, I mentioned that in the question "I tried to add the jar into the lib directory inside $ANT_HOME with no luck".

Comment: What happened to adding plugin dependencies? That should work...?

Answer (score 3):

The error message you posted shows you're using maven-antrun-plugin:1.3. I've found different solutions using version 1.3 of the plugin and version 1.7 of the plugin.

### Ant build.xml

```
<project name="ant-propertyfile" basedir=".">
    <target name="run">
        <propertyfile file="my.properties" comment="My properties">
            <entry key="progress" value="Made"/>
        </propertyfile>
    </target>
</project>
```

### maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 pom.xml

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <tasks>
            <ant antfile="build.xml" target="run"/>
          </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-optional</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3-1</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

### maven-antrun-plugin:1.7 pom.xml

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <configuration>
          <target>
            <ant antfile="build.xml" target="run"/>
          </target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```